# Common Lisp fuzzy-searchable function reference?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Is there a nice and friendly set of searchable documentation for ANSI Common Lisp anywhere? Preferably one that can be downloaded for use offline. I've Google but can only find static HTML pages that basically mean you need to know exactly what you're looking for.

I'm after something like http://erldocs.com/, where I can type something like "string" or "list" and all the matching functions come up instantly, for me to click on and browse easily.

Man pages are no use, since you need to know the exact function you need, while the searchable style allows you to discover functions without knowing them beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [CLHS: Symbol Index](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/X_Symbol.htm)
- [l1sp.org](http://l1sp.org)
- In Slime, type <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-d</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>, a few chars of your search term, and then <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get a completion list.
- Just type `(apropos "term")` in repl.

Comment: Those sites do the job, but nowhere near as easy to use as erldocs and much more using the browser back button ;) Sounds like there may be a project here!

Answer (score 1):

A downloadable version of the CLHS is available in info format:

```
ftp://gnu.org/gnu/gcl/gcl.info.tgz
```

Here's a handy emacs function to lookup the symbol under the point in the using F1:

```
(defun clhs-info ()
  (interactive)
  (ignore-errors
    (info (concatenate 'string "(gcl) " (thing-at-point 'symbol)))))

(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
    (define-key lisp-mode-map [f1] 'clhs-info)))
```

You can do partial matching using Info-index rather than concatenation as well.